# Manipulation TextInput selection

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

I'm trying to make a `TextInput` with a non-standard `placeholder`, because I need formatting and the normal, built-in TextInput `placeholder` doesn't work for me.

In order for the user to start writing from the beginning of the line, as with the normal placeholder, I set the cursor at the beginning of `selection={TEXT ? null: {start: 0}`. When the user types further, the cursor goes back to the beginning and forces the user to write `elloH` instead of `Hello`.

I made an example of my code on Snack, the problem will be clearer when running: https://snack.expo.dev/Vv6lNzUCU

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Samuli Hakoniemi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212878/samuli-hakoniemi) idea of `opacity` and `zIndex`, but I think I simplified the code a bit:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
  StyleSheet, 
  View, 
  TextInput, 
  Text
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [TEXT, setText] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 100, padding: 20 }}>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{ 
            padding: 5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            zIndex: 1,
          }}
          autoFocus={true}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setText(text);
          }}
          value={TEXT}
        />

        <View style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          left: 5,
          height: '100%',
          zIndex: 0,
          opacity: (TEXT) ? 0 : 1,
        }}>
          <Text>
            <Text>My </Text>
            <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>Example</Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Example in Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/mOuNbvxCU

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow your example but couldn't come up with all the things you're doing. So I made a new snack. It necessarily doesn't answer your question, but that is because you haven't elaborated all the reasons behind that.

What this does, is adding a custom placeholder to be seen when there's no text inside `TextInput`. And when you add some text, the placeholder will disappear.

Since you're trying to display the contents of written content, I made an assumption (sorry) that you're trying to build some kind of RTE kind of solution. Hence, I took your example and added the hook to highlight text content. So, try `highlightedKeywords` array for that.

Here is the complete solution to be tested: https://snack.expo.dev/@zvona/manipulation-textinput-selection

And here is the code in case Expo loses their snacks:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';

const highlightedKeywords = ['beep', 'boop'];

const App = () => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = React.useState('');

  const highlightContent = () => {
    const splitText = inputText.split(' ');

    return splitText.map((str) => {
      if (highlightedKeywords.includes(str)) {
        return <Text style={[styles.overlapText, styles.highlightedText]}>{str}</Text>;
      } else {
        return <Text style={styles.overlapText}>{str}</Text>;
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={setInputText} />
        <View style={styles.placeholder}>
          {inputText.length ? (
            <><Text>{highlightContent()}</Text></>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Text>This is my </Text>
              <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>Placeholder</Text>
            </>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },

  inputContainer: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: '100%',
    height: 35,
  },

  textInput: {
    zIndex: 2,
    borderColor: '#202020',
    borderWidth: 2,
    height: '100%',
    padding: 5,
    color: 'transparent',
  },

  placeholder: {
    zIndex: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'block',
    height: '100%',
    left: 7,
    top: 8,
  },

  overlapText: {
    marginRight: '0.25em',
  },

  highlightedText: {
    backgroundColor: '#6699CC',
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
});

export default App;
```